Strongly typed id in EF Core while projecting to some model
I try to query Postgresql DB on models with strongly typed ids and project to a model.
Cannot understand why query doesn't work.
It throws this exception:

Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException:
Translation of 'EF.Property(u3.Id, "ClientId")' failed.
Either the query source is not an entity type, or the specified property does not exist on the entity type.

If I remove the strongly typed IDs from the query and use a plain Guid instead, the query executes correctly and returns data from the database.
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        using var context = new EntityContext();

        var query = (from client in context.Clients
            let managers = from managerId in client.ManagerIds
                join user in context.Users on managerId equals user.Id
                select new { user.Id, user.Name }
            select new { client, managers }).ToList();
    }
}

public record UserId(Guid Value);
public record ClientId(Guid Value);

public class Client
{
    public ClientId Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserId> ManagerIds { get; set; } = new List<UserId>();
}

public record User(UserId Id, string Name);

public class EntityContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .Property(x => x.Id)
            .HasConversion(x => x.Value, x => new UserId(x));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Client>()
            .Property(x => x.Id)
            .HasConversion(x => x.Value, x => new ClientId(x));
        modelBuilder.Entity<Client>()
            .OwnsMany(
                client => client.ManagerIds, 
                ownedNavigationBuilder =>
                {
                    ownedNavigationBuilder
                        .WithOwner()
                        .HasForeignKey("ClientId");
                    ownedNavigationBuilder
                        .Property(x => x.Value)
                        .HasColumnName("ManagerId");
                }
            );
    }
}


Then why do it? Why engineer way of wrapping a guid up and calling it a ClientId, that adds nothing beneficial over what you get with a Guid? Will you do the same with ClientName, wrapping a string into a strongly typed string? Will you do it for every primitive in the project? Most of your classes will be primitive wrappers, most of your code will be conversion and creation wrangling.. Seems nonsensical to me

@flackoverstow Strongly typed IDs are a good practice to avoid introducing unexpected bugs into a project that can easily slip into production. It is arguably redundant for GUID keys though due to their unique nature. More suited to int. When you have a strongly typed ProductId for a Product table, vs. a PersonId for a Person table, if an order is meant to have a relationship to a Product, the compiler will alert you if you accidentally pass it a reference to a Person ID when person and product IDs are passed strongly typed. *even if they happen share the same underlying value.

Yeah, I understand the point, but EF provides similar protection anyway by allowing you to wire up relationships using objects not primitive IDs, for example  myOrder.Product = myProduct rather than introducing a bug of myOrder.ProductId = my person.Id. You aren't going to succeed with myOrder.Product = myPerson for similar reasons

This relationship doesn't look right:
        modelBuilder.Entity<Client>()
            .OwnsMany(
                client => client.ManagerIds, 
                ownedNavigationBuilder =>
                {
                    ownedNavigationBuilder
                        .WithOwner()
                        .HasForeignKey("ClientId");
                    ownedNavigationBuilder
                        .Property(x => x.Value)
                        .HasColumnName("ManagerId");
                }
            );

OwnsMany/HasMany are for relationships between entities, so I would expect Client to have an ICollection<User> Managers { get; } = []; Rather than a collection of UserIds. EF would be expecting the record to be an entity not a GUID. I suspect EF can store a list of GUIDs within a Client row, but a properly normalized many-to-many relationship would be better.
